# how to declare multiple cron job?

Tags: cron, nestjs

I want to register several schedules.
I used the @nestjs/schudule module of nestjs
I registered the schedule as below code.

```
 @Cron('0 0 0 1/1 * ? *', { name: '00:00 clock' })
  async resetApiExceed() {
    ....
  }

  @Cron('0 0 18,19,20,21,22 * * *', { name: '18~22 clock' })
  async handleInterval() {
    ...
  }
}
```

// I had an error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems like the underlying package that `@nestjs/scheduling` uses does not support the last argument that you added (`0 0 0 1/1 * ? *` the last one is *Year*)

the underlying package is [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) so to be compliant with the package syntax, i suggest you verify your syntax with theirs.
from the repo README:

> There are tools that help when constructing your cronjobs. You might find something like https://crontab.guru/ or https://cronjob.xyz/ helpful. But, note that these don't necessarily accept the exact same syntax as this library, for instance, it doesn't accept the seconds field, so keep that in mind.

also for your specific usage (job every midnight of every day in every month starting from the 1st of every month - which could be simplified to simply every day) there is an exact example in the repo:
https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/blob/master/examples/at_midnight.js